# ShaderMaterial does not work on Android Tablet

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use custom Shader Materials like this:

```
// UNIFORMS  
this.uniforms = {
                  "baseTexture": { type: "t", value: SSD.TEXTURES[texture] }
                };

this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { 
  uniforms: this.uniforms, 
  vertexShader: document.getElementById( shader+'Vertex' ).textContent, 
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById( shader+'Fragment' ).textContent,
  transparent: true
});
```

This works fine on my desktop PC, but my Nexus 7 Tablet does not show these textures. I've seen many three.js demos with ShadersMaterials that actually work on the Nexus, so I don't see, what the problem could be here.

Remote debugging of Chrome on Android says "S3TC compressed textures not supported".

Comment: well, what formats are your textures in? Maybe just use jpg or some other format that is supported? Are your textures in a power of two resolution?

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause I've had of this is textures that aren't a size that is a power of 2 (ex. 256x256 or 512x512). Most desktop GPUs seem to handle these just fine, but the tablet GPUs often don't. So check your texture sizes first.

*The note about compressed textures is always shown, even if you don't use them.*